# Access ID of parent model from associated model in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, associations

ok, I have the following models in rails:

- 'Shards'
- 'Realities' which either belong to a shard, or which belong to nothing
- 'Spaces' which belong to a reality
- 'Properties' which belong to spaces

I can access shard.reality.space.first.properties, but I'd like to be able to access the 'shard' id from a custom method in the property model if it has been accessed in this way.

Is there any way of doing this?

Comment: Somebody should point out that you're breaking some serious encapsulation here. The law of demeter (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter) is popularly interpreted as only-one-dot (even though that's an oversimplification) but what you're trying to do definitely violates it. The property should only know about itself and its members; the space is a "member", the shard is not. I'd look at how you're structuring that and see if you can figure out a better way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class Property < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :space

  def custom_method
    space.reality.shard.id if space.reality.shard
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Within an instance method on a `Property` object, this should work:

```
shard_id = space.reality.shard_id
# returns either the shard id, or nil if the reality doesn't belong to a shard
```